# ubuntu magento 2 phpmyadmin login page is not opening giving 404 error

Tags: magento2, 404, magento2.4.5

My website is working perfectly.
when i try to open mywebsitedomain/phpmyadmin it gives 404 error, It was working perfectly. Magento 2.4.5 on Ubuntu. Not find any resolution related to this issue.

Answer (score 0):

**It's Solved**
Risk of data lost if follow any step wrong. Read Carefully and take snapshot or backup of server.

1. Check phpmyadmin folder in /etc/* directry. If you found phpmyadmin folder then proceed to 6th step directly.
2. If you don't find the phpmyadmin folder. Then use command `sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin`

or  for custom php version use `sudo apt install phpmyadmin php7.4-mbstring php7.4-gettext -y` change 7.4 with required php version.

3. On popup **Tick apache2** with **space button** and **press enter**.
   [image]
4. After that select **no** for **database setup** if you already have Website database.
   [image]
5. After setup done check **/etc** directry in root folder. Now you find **phpmyadmin** folder in this Directory.
6. Use this command `sudo nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf` to open the file using **nano** then add the following line: `Include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf`
7. use `sudo service apache2 restart` to restart apache. clear cache storage from magento2 admin panel. now yourdomainurl/phpmyadmin will work.